# expected ')' before '*' token and conflicting types for 'function'

Tags: c, linux, file, header

Hey guys I'm working on a project for class that adds words from a file into a trie, compares it with another file and displays certain info. I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting these errors. In my dictstat.c file this is my code.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <ctype.h>
  4 #include "prototypes.h"
  5 
  6 typedef struct TrieNode
  7  {
  8  int isAWord ;
  9  char letter;
 10  int words;
 11  struct TrieNode* children[26];
 12  }Node;
 13 
 14 typedef struct TrieADT
 15  {
 16   Node* root;
 17  }MainTrie;
 18 
 19 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 20 
 21         MainTrie FirstTrie;
 22         MainTrie *Trie;
 23         Trie = &FirstTrie;
 24 
 25         FILE *f, *f2;
 26 
 27         if(argc !=  3){
 28           return 1;
 29         }
 30 
 31         f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 32         f2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
 33 
 34         if(f == NULL || f2 == NULL){
 35            return 1;
 36         }
 37 
 38         makeTrie(Trie);
 39 
 40         return 0;
 41 }
 42 
 43 
 44   Node *getNode(void) {
 45 
 46         int i;
 47         Node *newNode = NULL;
 48         newNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));//allocates space for new node
 49         newNode->isAWord = 0;
 50         newNode->letter = '/';
 51 
 52    if( newNode ){
 53 
 54         for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
 55 
 56            newNode->children[i] = NULL;//Sets elements in array equal to Null
 57 
 58         }
 59            return newNode;
 60         }
 61       }
 62 
 63 
 64   void makeTrie(MainTrie *pTrie){
 65 
 66         pTrie->root = getNode();
 67   }
 68 
 69  int addToTrie(char word[], int lengthOfWord, Node *TNode, int point){
 70 
 71         if(lengthOfWord == 0){//if the length of the word is 0 stop the function
 72 
 73             printf("No word.\n");
 74             return 0;
 75         }
 76 
 77         if(point >= lengthOfWord){//if the pointer is beyond the end of a word
 78 
 79            TNode->isAWord = 1;//then set the node to be the end of the word
 80            return 1;
 81         }
 82 
 83         if(TNode == NULL){//if Node is null end function
 84 
 85                 printf("Pointer is null.\n");
 86                 return 0;
 87         }
 88 
 89         if( TNode->children[(word[point])-'a'] == NULL ){//if there is no neighbor with letter
 90 
 91                 Node *newNode;
 92                 newNode = getNode();//Makes new node
 93                 newNode->letter = word[point];//Puts letter in new node
 94                 TNode->children[(word[point])-'a'] = newNode;//puts new node into trie
 95                 point = point + 1;//increments down the tree
 96                 printf("adding\n");
 97                 return addToTrie(&word[point-1], lengthOfWord, TNode->children[(word[point]) - 'a'], point);//Calls function again
 98         }
 99 
100         else{
101 
102                 printf("There is a neighbor.");//No new node to create
103                 return addToTrie(&word[point-1], lengthOfWord, TNode->children[(word[point]) - 'a'], point);
104             }
106
107    }
108  }
```

Here is my prototypes.h file.

```
  1 void readDict(FILE* dict_file);
  2 void scanData(FILE* data_file);
  3 void makeTrie(MainTrie *pTrie);
  4 int addToTrie(char word[], int lengthOfWord, Node* TNode, int point);
```

When I try to compile my .c file and .h file together I get the following error messages:

```
In file included from dictstat.c:4:
prototypes.h:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
prototypes.h:4: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Node’
dictstat.c:64: warning: conflicting types for ‘makeTrie’
dictstat.c:38: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘makeTrie’ was here
dictstat.c:69: error: conflicting types for ‘addToTrie’
prototypes.h:4: note: previous declaration of ‘addToTrie’ was here
prototypes.h:1: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
prototypes.h:2: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
prototypes.h:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
prototypes.h:4: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Node’
```

I'm new here, so I apologize if I screwed the format of this question up or it was answered already.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `.h` file should have `#include <stdio.h>` to make the name `FILE` visible. Your code compiles only because your `.c` file happens to include `<stdio.h>` before it includes `"prototypes.h"`. Headers should be includable in any order.

Comment: Please do some work in boiling your problem down before asking here. This may be a good start on how to organize yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: regarding this line: newNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));  If the malloc fails, then the next two lines are undefined behavior because there is nothing specific pointed to by newNode, which will probably result in a segmentation fault event.

Comment: the 'typedef struct...' items need to be in the header file, BEFORE the prototypes that use those struct definitions.

Comment: this line: struct TrieNode* children[26]; should be Node* children[26];

Comment: these lines:          MainTrie FirstTrie; and MainTrie *Trie; should be: Node FirstTrie; and Node *Trie;

Comment: the prototypes.h file is missing a protective wrapper.  Always put a protective wrapper around the contents of a header file, so it does not get included more than once.  Also, since the prototypes are using 'File', the appropriate header file (I'm thinking stdio.h) should be included before the prototypes.

Comment: This line: void makeTrie(MainTrie *pTrie){, and the prototype, should be: void makeTrie(Node *pTrie){ and void makeTrie(Node *pTrie);

Comment: Thank you all for the input you've helped me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define type `MainTrie` (and `TrieNode`) in the source file but include references to them in the header file  (in the function prototypes).

Solution: move the `typedef` / `struct` declarations to the header file.